# Include an artefact in one Visual Studio Team Services project in another project?

Tags: azure-devops, crfsuite

I'm using Visual Studio Team services to build [CRFSuite](https://github.com/chokkan/crfsuite) and [LibLBFGS](https://github.com/chokkan/liblbfgs).  CRFSuite depends on LibLBFGS library being built.  I can build LibLBFGS without issue.  I want to be able to have the library and header file that are generated by the LibLBFGS build included in the CRFSuite project when I build that.

Hopefully I am missing something pretty obvious and this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to achieve your requirement is that, you can add another Visual Studio Build or other to build LibLBFGS project to your CRFSuite build definition.

Steps:

1. Create build definition for CRFSuite project (e.g. Visual Studio build template)
2. Set mappings for LibLBFGS and CRFSuite projects in Repository tab
3. Add Visual Studio Build step/task (build LibLBFGS project) before step/task of building CRFSuite project
4. Add Copy files step/task to copy LibBFGS build result (artifacts) to corresponding folder according how CRFSuite project is referenced

On the other hand, if you are familiar to the PowerShell, you can custom build task to call REST API to download artifact of other build. [There](https://github.com/chamindac/vsts.release.task.download-artifacts/blob/master/DownloadArtifacts/DownloadArtifacts/download-artifacts/DownloadArtifacts.ps1) is the sample code that can help you.